# Problema ao tentar chamar uma função dentro do onPress - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

Olá,
Ao tentar chamar uma função que tem uma hook call aparece o seguinte erro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui está o trecho do código:

**currentLocation.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

export function locationUser(){
  ...
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({
    latitude:0,
    longitude: 0,
    error: null
  });
  ...
  return console.log(coordinates); 
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { locationUser } from '../../services/currentLocation'

export default function Home(){

    return(
      <View>
        ...
        <Button onPress={() => locationUser()}>
          <Text>INICIAR</Text>
        </Button>
        ...
      </View>
  );
}
```

se tentar executar **locationUser** sem está dentro da arrow fuction funciona, porém, não fica certo, pois a função ficará executando infinitamente, já que uma função normal executa assim que o código é iniciado.

Alguém pode me ajudar? =)

Answer (score 0):

Vc tem que tomar alguns cuidados ao usar JavaScript, principalmente misturando ES5 com ES6

Leia um pouco mais sobre This, Bind, Apply

https://tableless.com.br/react-this-bind-so-sei-que-assim/

Comment: Mais no meu caso estou usando Function Component e não Class Component, em que parte você acha que estou misturando?